# Can I package MongoDB with node js using pkg or anything similar?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, exe

I need to package MongoDB(community edition) along with NodeJS to exe file so that the user just to execute a single exe file and MongoDB installs automatically. Can I do it? If yes, how?

Comment: Look into tools like 'Windows installer' perhaps?